# Javascript split between slash and dot

Tags: javascript, split

Hi guys i've got this string

> "novyProjekt/images/icons/ashe.png"

And i need split it between icons/ and .png. So i need only "ashe". 
Thank you for answer

```
function highlight(img)
{

    var source = img.src;
    var splitSource = source.split("/");
    var splitedSource = splitSource[6].split(".");
    //img.src = "images/icons/"+splitedSource[0]+"1.png";

}
```

This is my code but it is not very effective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
 <script>
 function f()
 {
  var ss1="novyProjekt/images/icons/ashe.png";
  var ss2= ss1.substring(ss1.lastIndexOf("/")+1,ss1.lastIndexOf("."));
  alert(ss2);
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = new RegExp("icons\/(.*)\.png", "g");
var myArray = str.match(re);
```

The `myArray[1]` holds the filename without extension i.e. 'ashe'